# Get maximum subset in multidimensional array

Tags: python

Given:

```
a=np.array([[-0.00365169, -1.96455717,  1.44163783,  0.52460176,  2.21493637], 
            [-1.05303533, -0.7106505,   0.47988974,  0.73436447, -0.87708389],
            [-0.76841759,  0.8405524,   0.91184575, -0.70652033,  0.37646991]])
```

I would like to get the maximum subset (in this case, the first row):

```
[-0.00365169, -1.96455717,  1.44163783,  0.52460176,  2.21493637]
```

By using `print(np.amax(a, axis=0))`, I'm getting the wrong result:

```
[-0.00365169  0.8405524   1.44163783  0.73436447  2.21493637]
```

How can we get the correct maximum subset?

Comment: What is your definition of "maximum subset"?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Probably yes. Most other questions only ask for the maximum values, but no one really answers for the maximum array.
@GZ0 I mean the maximum array.
Why the first one is the maximum because It has `-0.00365169 1.44163783  2.21493637` while the other arrays have only one maximum value.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I'm trying to find the maximum array as an array and not by value

Comment: It's still not clear what maximum subset means. You mentioned the first row is "maximum" in some sense. Is it because of the `2.21`? I'm not sure why `-0.003` has any effect in determining that it is "maximum".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can `sum` along columns and then find the index with the maximum value with `argmax`:

```
a[np.argmax(a.sum(axis=1))]
```

Comment: Why is there an `np.sum`?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq OP needs the row with a maximum sum.

Comment: But how do you know that? OP never used the words `addition` nor `sum`.

Answer (score 0):

If you make some change:

```
a=np.array([[-0.00365169, -10.96455717,  1.44163783,  0.52460176,  2.21493637], 
            [-1.05303533, -0.7106505,   0.47988974,  0.73436447, -0.87708389],
            [-0.76841759,  0.8405524,   0.91184575, -0.70652033,  0.37646991]])
```

The solution will be not right:

```
a[np.argmax(a.sum(axis=1))]
```

Try this:

```
arr = np.where(a == np.amax(a, axis=0))[0]
counts = np.unique(arr)
ind = np.argmax(counts)
print(a[arr[ind]])
```

Comment: Something is wrong with your solution.
The result is correct only for the first time. If you update again the array, the output is not the same. You cant try it. 
The first solution from @Mykola is more robust.